# How do you paint text onto a curved surface?

Tags: texture-painting

Here I have an image showing a poor attempt to get text to fit nicely on this bra-like mesh. Two objects are shown in the scene, one is just my attempt to recreate the UV as an object to see if that might help me paint the texture on. Didn't seem to help.

I also tried a single UV island. But the UV-unwrap is too warped. See second image, notice the next drops at an angle `\` when it should be straight across `_`.

I of course also tried stencil painting, but the curved surface is such at some of the surface (on the sides) curves behind the front surface. Stencil-painting a single character at a time is another option but it's so imprecise I'd rather use some other imprecise method.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to modify the UV map once unwrap? Or create a rather flat object, unwrap it, then modiffy it in the 3D view so that it takes the shape you want? Maybe share your object so that we can try?

Comment: how do I share objects? for the life of me I can't find an attachment feature on this website. here's google drive link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Wh3Kpk8yqPj5mCpsjckl8JwvKpsKLV1_?usp=sharing

Comment: follow the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/